# Central Python third party package library on network share

Tags: python, pip, conda, libraries, anaconda3

I've been asked to come up with a way to centralize our python third party packages at work.  That sounds simple enough, use a pip server or conda server.  Now here is the constraint, I cannot use a server, only a network share.  I've researched everywhere to find a way to do this but no one has a straight forward method.  Does anybody have a solution to this type of problem that you use at work??  Preferably open source or free.  Thanks.

Comment: If you "*cannot use a server, only a network share*", what software solution do you envision? You probably already have the network share.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution that combines user configuration for .rc files or ini file and some static index building on the share.

Comment: You don't need a `conda server`, you can have a local folder function as a conda channel

Comment: I've tested the conda server in a folder and that works great, thanks for the suggestion.  I also got pip working with a folder but pip search is DOA.  Any ideas?